# blockquote hidden in emails

Tags: html, email

Our system has an option to send out emails when the status of a file is changed.  You can attach a message to the status change and it'll be sent in the email.

Here's an example email:

```html
File 1234 has been updated by <b>John Smith</b> with a status of <q>Updated</q> with an attached message of:<br/><br/>
<blockquote>Updated the file</blockquote>
<br/>
```

When these emails are sent, they have the subject: `Status update for file 1234`.

Zimbra, and most other email clients, will group multiple emails from the same file into the same "conversation".  For some reason, if 2 emails are sent with the same status message, the message is hidden in the email.  You need to click "show quoted text" to show the "hidden" message.

My boss didn't notice the "show quoted text" link, and complained that the emails were blank.

How can I make email clients not hide text it thinks is "quoted"?  Why does it think my `<blockquote>` tag is a quote from the previous email that happens to contain the same text?

Comment: Because the software is crap. Use a different tag.

Comment: @Diodeus: I just tested it in Gmail.  It does the same thing.  What's wrong with the `<blockquote>` tag?

Comment: Perhaps this is more of a "ebkac" problem: error between keyboard and chair.

Comment: @Diodeus: On my part or my boss' part?

Comment: Email has really limited HTML support.  It's super basic.  Stay away from fancy formatters (read: ALL THE HTML5's); use tables and spans almost exclusively.  Clients will actually hide content that they can understand for consistency between views.

Comment: @SandyGifford: The `<blockquote>` tag works when there is only one email in the "conversation", but when there's more, it thinks the `<blockquote>` is "quoted" text from the previous email(s).

Comment: Is that true across all clients?

Comment: @SandyGifford: I've only tested it in Gmail and Zimbra.

Comment: **shudder** Zimbra...  Anyway, if I had to guess, some email clients remove styling in reply threads (so they don't get visually confused with the current message).  It could be that whatever client wrote the reply email didn't have a case for removing formatting from a blockquote tag and just decided to nuke the whole thing.  Either way, I wouldn't use the tag.  Try using a `<p style = "style your block quote here">` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> You don't have to use the `blockquote` tag. Try a `div` or `p` with a style attribute instead.

e.g. in the `style`:

```
p.blockquote {
  font: 14px/22px normal helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
}
```

and in the HTML:
`<p class="blockquote">...</p>`

Answer (score 2):

the p tag is more versatile and is allowed in mail clients more often than blockquote.